# Multiple standalone documents

Tags: plot, standalone

I have to create many figures(100s) with the same template.

Here is what I do now:

```
\documentclass[multi,crop,border=2]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,pgfplotstable}

\standaloneenv{my}

\begin{document}

\foreach \n in {1,...,5} {
\begin{my}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xmin=-10,xmax=10,ymin=-10,ymax=10,samples=50]
  \addplot[blue, ultra thick] (x,\n*x*x);
  % Usually, at this point, I read the data from a file named 'data\n.dat'
  %\addplot [red, very thick]table [x index=0, y index =1] {data\n.dat};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{my}
}

\end{document}
```

Then I split the output pdf into individual pages using some tool.

Is there any way I can make `standalone` class output individual pdf files?

Comment: So you use `1,...,5` in your example code, but actually you have more like `1,...,100`?

Comment: Not within TeX without an external program. You are better of to use a PDF split program yourself. There are several open source tools for that. Also note that you can use `page` on `\includegraphics` or `\includestandalone` to import specific pages.

Comment: @Werner: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @SaravanaKumar: To answer your question: No. You can write a batch script to process each of the figures separately and write them to a new file upon completion, or process everything as a whole and then split them into separate files.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, you could externalize the tikz picture. This will not split the standalone into multiple pages, but will create an individual document for each iteration of the `tikzpicture`.

```
\documentclass[multi,crop,border=2]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,pgfplotstable}

\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize


\standaloneenv{my}

\begin{document}

\foreach \n in {1,...,5} {
\begin{my}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xmin=-10,xmax=10,ymin=-10,ymax=10,samples=50]
  \addplot[blue, ultra thick] (x,\n*x*x);
  % Usually, at this point, I read the data from a file named 'data\n.dat'
  %\addplot [red, very thick]table [x index=0, y index =1] {data\n.dat};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{my}
}

\end{document}
```